# Apply Zip function on Pandas Dataframe using a For Loop Argument

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a function called handle text that renames values in dataframe columns:

```
def handle_text(txt):
if txt.lower()[:6] == 'deu_ga': 
    return 'Western Europe', 'Germany'
elif txt.lower()[:6] == 'fra_ga':
    return 'Western Europe', 'France'
return 'Other', 'Other'
```

I apply handle_text on various dataframes in the following way:

```
campaigns_df['Region'], campaigns_df['Market']  = zip(*campaigns_df['Campaign Name'].apply(handle_text))

atlas_df['Region'], atlas_df['Market']  = zip(*atlas_df['Campaign Name'].apply(handle_text))

flashtalking_df['Region'], flashtalking_df['Market']  = zip(*flashtalking_df['Campaign Name'].apply(handle_text))
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do a for loop to apply the function to various dfs at once:

```
dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df, innovid_df, ias_viewability_df, ias_fraud_df]
columns_df = ['Campaign Name']

for df in dataframes:
    for column in df.columns:
        if column in columns_df:
            zip(df.column.apply(handle_text))
```

However the error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df, innovid_df, ias_viewability_df, ias_fraud_df, mediaplan_df]
columns_df = 'Campaign Name'

for df in dataframes:
    df['Region'], df['Market'] = zip(*df[columns_df].apply(handle_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Need change attribute acces by `.` to more general by `[]`:

```
zip(df.column.apply(handle_text))
```

to

```
zip(df[column].apply(handle_text))
```

EDIT:

Better solution:

```
atlas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign Name':['deu_gathf', 'deu_gahf', 'fra_gagg'],'another_col':[1,2,3]})
flashtalking_df = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign Name':['deu_gahf','fra_ga', 'deu_gatt'],'another_col':[4,5,6]})

dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df]
columns_df = 'Campaign Name'
```

You can `map` by `dict` and then create new columns:

```
d = {'deu_ga': ['Western Europe','Germany'], 'fra_ga':['Western Europe','France']}

for df in dataframes:
    df[['Region','Market']] = pd.DataFrame(df[columns_df].str.lower()
                                                         .str[:6]
                                                         .map(d)
                                                         .values.tolist())

     #print (df)

print (atlas_df)
  Campaign Name  another_col          Region   Market
0     deu_gathf            1  Western Europe  Germany
1      deu_gahf            2  Western Europe  Germany
2      fra_gagg            3  Western Europe   France

print (flashtalking_df)
  Campaign Name  another_col          Region   Market
0      deu_gahf            4  Western Europe  Germany
1        fra_ga            5  Western Europe   France
2      deu_gatt            6  Western Europe  Germany
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I set the result of the for loop to create two new columns for each df: 

`new_columns = ['Region', 'Market']` 

I tried placing:

            `df.new_columns = zip(df[column].apply(handle_text))`
at the end of the for loop but nothing comes up when I call one of the dfs

Comment: Hmm, why do you use `zip`? Is it necessary?

Comment: If I don't use zip when I apply the function in the old way, that is:

`atlas_df['Region'], atlas_df['Market']  = zip(*atlas_df['Campaign Name'].apply(handle_text))`

then I get the following error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I think it's necessary to make sure that the function generates the two different columns (Region and Market) so that it can assign `Western Europe` to the newly created `Region` column and `Germany` to the newly created `Market` column on the `atlas_df`

Comment: Yes, i have question - in `columns_df = ['Campaign Name']` can be multiple values?

Comment: Not necessarily. If it's easier for a solution we can go with:

`dataframes = [atlas_df, flashtalking_df, innovid_df, ias_viewability_df, ias_fraud_df]
new_columns = ['Region', 'Market']
for df in dataframes:
    for column in df.columns:
        if 'Campaign Name' in column:
            df.new_columns = zip(df[column].apply(handle_text))`

However when I recall atlas_df, there is no atlas_df['Market] and no atlas_df['Region]

Comment: I add solution, please check it. It filter column by name `columns_df` and map.